# Unique constraint in many to many relationship

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I am working on a python project. In this project i am using sqlalchemy. There are two tables: notes and tags and a third table notes_tags that creates the many to many relationship.
This third table is defined this way:

```
class NotesTags(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'notes_tags'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    note_id = Column('note_id', Integer, ForeignKey('notes.id'))
    note = relationship(Notes)
    tag_id = Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'))
    tag = relationship(Tags)
```

and when i save a record to this table, i do it this way:

```
notesTags.tag = newtag
notesTags.note = givenNote
session.add(notesTags)
```

And on my database i get something like this:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | note_id | tag_id |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |      83 |      1 |
|  2 |     108 |      1 |
|  3 |     114 |      1 |
|  4 |     119 |      1 |
|  5 |     124 |      1 |
+----+---------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

But then if i run the process again, the records get duplicated, that means i wold get something like this:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | note_id | tag_id |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |      83 |      1 |
|  2 |     108 |      1 |
|  3 |     114 |      1 |
|  4 |     119 |      1 |
|  5 |     124 |      1 |
|  6 |      83 |      1 |
|  7 |     108 |      1 |
|  8 |     114 |      1 |
|  9 |     119 |      1 |
| 10 |     124 |      1 |
+----+---------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

which is not a desired result. How can i ensure that records are not ducplicated?
I have thought of the following:
a) Check if there is already an existing record with the given note_id - tag_id before i save the record.
b) Create a composite id for the table that uses note_id and tag_id

I am not sure of how to create the second and also what is the best option to implement or how else can i achieve this.

I am connecting to a mysql database if that makes any difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using UNIQUE constraint in your table meta, like
`__table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('note_id', 'tag_id'),)` in your NotesTags table declaration

Comment: @NishantPatel i'll give it a try and see if it works